# Put list into dict with first row header as keys

Tags: python

I have the following python list:

```
[['A,B,C,D'],
 ['1,2,3,4'],
 ['5,6,7,8']]
```

How can I put it into a dict and use the first sub list as the keys?:

```
{'A': '1',
 'B': '2',
 'C': '3',
 'D': '4'}
{'A': '5',
 'B': '6',
 'C': '7',
 'D': '8'}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like two separate dictionaries, what actual format do you want? Also how do you have such a strange format, where is the data coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with your data as presented in the question:

```
>>> a = [['A,B,C,D'], ['1,2,3,4'], ['5,6,7,8']]
```

Now, let's convert that to the desired list of dictionaries:

```
>>> [dict(zip(a[0][0].split(','), c[0].split(','))) for c in a[1:]]
[{'A': '1', 'C': '3', 'B': '2', 'D': '4'}, {'A': '5', 'C': '7', 'B': '6', 'D': '8'}
```

Comment: While this works for this specific case a list won't typically look like this.  

A typical list will be [['A', 'B','C','D'], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5,6,7,8]] And this solution does not work for those cases as I learned the hard way.

Comment: @Eric.  Yes, very true:  Your list does not have any strings which need to have `.split(',')` applied to them.  Consequently, the code that you need will be different from the code that solves the OP's question here.

Answer (score 3):

You can `zip` the first element of the list with the remaining elements of the list after splitting the string in each sublist:

```
# to split string in the sublists
lst = [i[0].split(',') for i in lst]

[dict(zip(lst[0], v)) for v in lst[1:]]

#[{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '4'},
# {'A': '5', 'B': '6', 'C': '7', 'D': '8'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instance.  People usually use these with a file object, but actually it doesn't really care what you pass it as long as it can iterate the thing.

```
>>> L = [['A,B,C,D'],
...  ['1,2,3,4'],
...  ['5,6,7,8']]
>>> import csv
>>> reader = csv.DictReader((line for [line] in L))
>>> d1, d2 = reader
>>> d1
{'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '4'}
>>> d2
{'A': '5', 'B': '6', 'C': '7', 'D': '8'}
```

Comment: I think  `csv.DictReader((row[0] for row in l))` reads a bit better.

Comment: I prefer the code to raise `ValueError` if any sublist in `L` has more than one element.